# "Commutivity" or "commutativity"

Tags: mathematics, morphology

I see *commutivity* used in contexts where the meaning appears to be the same as *commutativity*. Here are an [example from physics](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=415943) and [another example](http://www.gydlepublishing.com/blog/2011/10/linguistic-commutivity/).
Is *commutivity* incorrect? Does it differ from *commutativity*?

Comment: I'm guessing these are simple misspellings.

Comment: I've never heard of `commutivity`. Even spell-checker marks it wrong.

Comment: I have up-voted your question, as I had often wondered about that myself:)

Answer (score 8):

The correct form is *commutativity* (*commutivity* isn't listed in OED). [Here's a usage chart](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=commutivity,commutativity&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) showing that the incorrect form isn't used very often, so it doesn't seem likely to take over any time soon.

[image]

Google gives you a pretty strong hint if you search for [Rubin's commutivity principle](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=Rubin%27s+commutivity+principle&oq=Rubin%27s+commutivity+principle&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=hp.3...11420427l11420427l1l11421064l1l1l0l0l0l0l49l49l1l1l0.frgbld.&psj=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=13e771909c591aa&biw=1290&bih=902) - it says *"About 2470 results"* and asks *"Did you mean: Rubin's **commutativity** principle"*. If you search for the suggested alternative instead, it produces *"About 1,200,000 results"*. Case closed, I think.

Comment: Right. The Commutative Law or Commutative Property are common in math, and the normal way to name a property after an adjective ending in _-ive_ is with _-ivity._ But you still need that _-ta-_ in front of the _-tivity._

Comment: @John: It seems like all my life I've been slightly disorientated by the question of whether I should really be disoriented. Thanks to the power of Google Books, I now see that back when I was trying to get to grips with such things, [British English was decidedly undecided on the matter](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=oriented+towards%2Corientated+towards&year_start=1900&year_end=1975&corpus=6&smoothing=3)

Comment: Is Google really the authority on correct English now? Is there an argument either way from a known, published language rule? Or is this a gray area?

Comment: @EliRosencruft: Google and NGrams is not an authority and it has its data collection problems and can't always be taken at face value (it counts whatever you ask; you need to ask things the right way). but it does give a good idea of how people tend to use things. People may make 'mistakes' more often than the 'correct' version, but simply by popularity the 'mistake' becomes 'correct'. But that's also a judgement call.

Comment: @Eli Rosencruft: Before I made any reference to Google Books, I did point out in my answer that *"**commutivity** isn't listed in OED"*. I then specifically added the results from a search for *"**Rubin's** commutativity principle"*, on the grounds that people who had heard of that were more likely to be familiar with the correct spelling. The chart was partly to reassure OP that *commutivity* does in fact occur (albeit at a relatively low level), so his question wasn't completely ridiculous.